# What is the font in this menubar?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, web-fonts

Does anyone have any idea on what font this is?

[image]

If there is more than 1 font, please identify that for me!

Many Thanks,
SparkzWeb

Comment: Did you try the font identification services which were posted in answer to your previous question?

Comment: There is more than one, because there are two forms of M illustrated. However, it looks like Gotham or Avenir. Have you looked in the styles specified in the web page? Very often a name is given explictly. With this sort of question, (a) **list what resources you have tried already** as that saves others repeating your work; (b) give a high-quality large image of the font if at all possible -- you may need to find other larger examples on the site; (c) give a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snowball summit logo is an image but i recognized the font (even tried in photoshop). The "snowball" font is Gotham Bold and the "summit" is Gotham Thin. Menu written with Proxima Nova. The most characteristic looking between these fonts is the "M" letter. The center of the Gotham's "M" letter is shorter than Proxima's. I hope this will work for you.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The "snowball summit" is purely an image. You can try [**Whatthefont**](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) or other similar online font identification engines. Please try this first.

The font of the menu is [**proxima-nova**](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/marksimonson/proxima-nova/)

You can go into the source code to find this. Depending on your browser (i use chrome), you can right-click the menu, and choose inspect element. That should give you the css name for the font.